# Using Future[JsValue] in a subsequent function Play framework 2.6x

Tags: json, scala, playframework, future, jsvalue

I'm new to play framework (2.6.x) and Scala. I have a function that returns a Future[JsValue]. How can I use the Future[JsValue] in a subsequent function?

```
def getInfo(): Future[JsValue] ={}
```

The following function will use a value from the JsValue to compute something.

Somewhere in middle I have to extract a value from the json response. `val currentWeight = (jsValue \ "weight").as[String].toDouble`

```
def doubleAmounts(currentWeight: Double): Double = {
  currentWeight*2.0
}
```

Whats the proper way of handling a Future here? Should I use a map or onComplete to get the `weight` from json?

I tried this but it only resolves after I have already called `doubleAmounts()`.

```
val weight = getInfo() map { response =>
  if (response.toString().length > 0) (response \ "weight").as[String])
  else throw new Exception("didn't get response")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, once that you start talking in `Futures`, you need to keep talking in `Futures`, the idea is that the same server will handle all this waits and context changes, so play it self can handle your promise that at some piont, you will return a result.

So, instead of calling functions in your controllers that return an `Any`, play can handle `Future[Any]`.

```
val weight: Future[String] = getInfo() map { response =>
  if (response.toString().length > 0) (response \ "weight").as[String])
  else throw new Exception("didn't get response")
}
```

If you have several future calls, where each one needs the result from other Future, you can use *For comprehension* to avoid a map hell. For example, here is a little more complex example:

```
 def processSync(databaseServer: DatabaseServer, databaseIdentity: DatabaseIdentity): Future[String] = {
    val info = for {
      catalogs <- databaseSyncService.getCatalogs(databaseServer.address, databaseServer.port, databaseIdentity.login, databaseIdentity.password)
      clubbers <- getClubbers(databaseServer.id)
      ignoredCatalogs <- ignoredCatalogService.get(databaseServer.id)
    } yield (catalogs, clubbers, ignoredCatalogs)
    val result = info.map{
      case(catalogs, clubbers, ignoredCatalogs) => {
        val currentCatalogs = (clubbers.map(clubber =>
          Seq(Some(clubber.mainSchema), clubber.archiveSchema, clubber.blacklistSchema, clubber.logsSchema).flatten
        ).flatten ++  ignoredCatalogs).toSet
        val serverCatalogs = catalogs.toSet
        if(currentCatalogs == serverCatalogs) {
          "synchronized"
        } else {
          "outOfSync"
        }
      }
    }.recover{
      case sqlE: SQLServerException =>{
        logger.error(s"Conection error with ${databaseServer.name}", sqlE)
        "connectionError"
      }
    }
    for{
      realResult <- result
      _ <- databaseServerRepo.updateSync(databaseServer.id, realResult)
    } yield realResult
  }
```

Each value in the for is a future, but bellow we can access their value, at the end of the for, you use yield to mark what need to be returned.

Other example could be this controller call (ignore the shilouete part, is an authentication library, simply think of the return type as a Future[Result]):

```
def sync(id: Int) = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request: SecuredRequest[DefaultEnv, AnyContent] =>
    val actions = for {
      (server, identity) <- databaseServerService.getWithIdentity(id)
      databaseCatalogs <- databaseSyncService.getCatalogs(server.address, server.port, identity.login, identity.password)
      ignoredCatalogs <- ignoredCatalogService.get(id)
      clubberIntegrations <- clubberIntegrationService.getClubbersListOrAutoFill(id, databaseCatalogs, ignoredCatalogs.map(_.name))
    } yield Future.successful {
      val catalogs = databaseCatalogs.map { x =>
        val ignoredCatalogNotes = ignoredCatalogs.filter(_.name == x).map(_.note).headOption
        DatabaseCatalog(x, ignoredCatalogNotes.getOrElse(""), ignoredCatalogNotes.isDefined)
      }
      Ok(web.databaseserver.views.html.databaseServerSync(request.identity, server, DatabaseServerForSync(clubberIntegrations, catalogs)))
    }
    actions.recover {
      case _: SQLServerException => {
        databaseServerService.getName(id).map(x => {
          Redirect(web.databaseserver.controllers.routes.DatabaseServerController.list())
            .flashing("error" -> Messages("databaseSync.couldNotConnect", x))
        })
      }
    }.flatMap(x => x)
  }
```

Also, i forgot to mention, if you need to handle a function that uses a Future and other does not, you can transform the latter with `Future.successful`, there is also `Future.sequence` to convert a `Seq[Future[Any]]` into `Future[Seq[Any]]` and other functions to help you handle the futures in different ways.